# How to route ALL traffic through Privoxy?

Tags: internet, vpn

I have a Raspberry Pi Privoxy server setup in my house, where I can connect to it through VPN. However, it seems as if Privoxy only routes HTTP and HTTPS traffic through the proxy. Is there a way I can route all of my traffic through the proxy so I can access my NAS, printers, etc (I know you can add these devices to the VPN, but I want to make this system expandable without too much work...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a quick look at Privoxy...

> Privoxy is a non-caching web proxy with advanced filtering capabilities for enhancing privacy, modifying web page data and HTTP headers, controlling access, and removing ads and other obnoxious Internet junk.

It is only intended to work with HTTP connections.  Other protocols are outside of it's remit.

The VPN should allow you to connect your "outside" devices to your "internal" network without having to reconfigure the other devices.  How you do that depends on what VPN you're using.